# how to load images from resources

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

How can I load images from resource folder in my GridView Adapter ?

I have a 200 images in resource folder i named them as name_1.png,name_2.png.

I want to load image and text view into android gridview element and show the images according to the number from resource folder.

I am able to show the text view data but not the images.

can any one suggest me how to do this. I am thinking that I have to write code in getview method to change the image.

This is getview method that I tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your images into drawable folder and reach them by name, then you access them by name.

```
int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", 
      context.getPackageName());
```

Then you can use the resource

```
 imageView.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

or

```
 imageView.setBackgroundResource(resourceId);
```

Comment: I make it like this :
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
   int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("name_of_image"+i, "drawable", 
          context.getPackageName());

and then what ? 
  like this ? how to display it?
 view.ivTowar.setImageDrawable(resourceId);
  }

Comment: Works correctly! I've got one more question. Actually the problem is, that name_of_imagei load the same images to diffrent categories becouse of the same execution for every category.. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

just a convenient refactoring of the accepted answer if you use kotlin and like using its extensions functions:

```
fun ImageView.loadDrawableFromName(name:String, ctx: Context, visible:Int=View.VISIBLE){
    val resId = ctx.resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", ctx.packageName)
    this.setImageResource(resId)
    this.visibility = visible
}
```

you can call it in both ways:

```
imgname="IMGNAME"
myimageview.loadDrawableFromName(imgname, ctx)
```

and

```
imgname="IMGNAME"
myimageview.loadDrawableFromName("@drawable/$imgname", ctx)
```